# Converting Proteus .GBR file to the more conventional Gerber extensions

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I am using a panelizer program used in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYrUztOn3dU&t=587s). unfortunatly upon adding the gerber files to the program the program doesnt seem to draw the body in the viewport. This lead me to believe that maybe it doenst understand the file names.

Reading the usage note

- .txt or .xln = excellon drill file.
- .gko = outline file.
- .gml = mill file. MAKE SURE YOU DO NOT INCLUDE THE BOARD OUTLINE IN THE MILL FILE AGAIN!!!
- gbl/gbo/gbs/gtl/gto/gts and the above will be used for image generation
- all other files (if gerber) will be combined with files with matching extension (case insensitive!)

And Proteus exports with .GBR only

[image]

I read that ggerber files are backwards/forward compatible meaning i can rename the extension no problem. The problem is i do not know which extension goes where 
and which files should be combined(same extention).

Comment: https://d33v4339jhl8k0.cloudfront.net/docs/assets/59f1de7804286313cffbb22c/images/5a094e8a04286331992465cf/file-UGBUPNOf6w.png  from your JLCPCB site

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 its not the gerber equivalent that is hard it actually the proteus equivalent that i do not know, for example the top layer, what is the proteus equivalent? Is it the top assembly,copper,solder resist or a combination.

Comment: Gerber files define the images required to make the PC board - copper layers, silkscreen, solder mask, etc.  They do not contain any information about the component bodies, because that is not required to make the bare PC board.

Comment: "CADCAM Top Copper.GBR" sounds like it contains the copper patttern for the top (component side) of the board. Some CAD programs may use the ".gtl" extension for that file.